# gwt: create SplitLayoutPanel using UIBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am trying to come up with a Layout using the SplitPanelLayout. I basically copied this code here and adapted it a little bit:

http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2324

My version

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:style>
    .eastPanel {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .westPanel {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .northPanel {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .southPanel {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .centerPanel {
        background-color: orange;
    }
    </ui:style>
    <g:SplitLayoutPanel>
        <g:north size="60" unit="EM">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.northPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the NORTH panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:north>
        <g:west size="200" unit="EM">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.westPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the WEST panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:west>
        <g:center>
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.centerPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the CENTER panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:center>
        <g:east size="200" unit="EM">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.eastPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the EAST panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:east>
        <g:south size="60" unit="EM">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.southPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the SOUTH panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:south>
    </g:SplitLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The problem is that the segments are stacked on top of each other. How do I fix that? And is there an overview of all the uibinder-tags somewhere?

**EDIT**

```
<g:SplitLayoutPanel>
        <g:north size="60" unit="EM">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.northPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the NORTH panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:north>
        <g:west size="3200" unit="PX">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.westPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the WEST panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:west>
        <g:center size="60" unit="EM">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.centerPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the CENTER panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:center>
        <g:east size="3200" unit="PX">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.eastPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the EAST panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:east>
        <g:south size="60" unit="EM">
            <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.southPanel}">
                <g:Label>This is the SOUTH panel</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:south>
    </g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

Comment: Is your document in _standards mode_?

Comment: This enables standards mode: <!doctype html>, right? If so, then the document is in standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

What is your EM? If it's standard 16px, you set east and west regions to be 3200 pixels wide each. Try to use pixels (`PX`) or percent (`PCT`) for your sizes.

Comment: See my edit: Now all I see is the blue north panel. What do you mean by whether my EM is 16px?

Comment: EM is a CSS unit of measure, which is linked to the font size set on the body tag. By default, it is 16px.

Comment: Replace all "EM" with "PX" or "PCT" and set real values. 3200 pixels for one region is way too much - it won't fit on any screen.

Comment: I changed the values now. The problem is that the divs all have absolute positioning and are positioned on top of each other. Do I have to completely change the default behaviour of those panels in my Css?

Comment: You should not set size on the center region.

Comment: Still not... the only thing that happened now is that the center region is as high as the font size of the text in it.